# How to delete all files in the folder which exists in the tar.gz archive

Tags: command-line, zsh, archiving

Typical mistake for me, is exctraction in the wrong directory.

After i realize that, i want to delete all this file, and extract again.

But how to automate this delete-all-this-crap operation?

Any suggestions?

UPD: linux machine (zsh)

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: And are you positive that none of the files in the directory were also there before extracting the archive? Or there were same-named files that were overwritten by the archive files?

Comment: sorry, linux, yeah i am positive anyway files already died

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
tar -tzf archive.tar.gz | sed 's@^//*@@' | sort -r | xargs -d '\n' rm -d
```

If your archive contains absolute paths and you unpacked it to the absolute locations (for this you need to use the `-P` option of `tar`) you have to leave out `sed`. You can also leave `sed` out, if you are absolutely sure that there are no absolute paths in your archive.

```
tar -tzf archive.tar.gz | sort -r | xargs -d '\n' rm -d
```

#### Explanation

You can get a list of the files in a tar.gz archive by using the `-t` option:

```
tar -tzf archive.tar.gz
```

If there is the slightest chance that there are absolute paths in your archive and you did *not* unpack using the `-P` option for tar (which would unpack to the absolute locations instead of the current or given directory), you need to strip leading slashes from the file list, because `tar -tf` will always show them. `sed` can help with that:

```
tar -tzf archive.tar.gz | sed 's@^//*@@'
```

Takes the pattern between the first and second `@` - `^//*`, which matches one or more `/` at the beginning of a line - and replaces it with the string between the second and third `@` - in this case with nothing, effectively removing the match.

With `xargs` you can the output of one command as arguments to another:

```
tar -tzf archive.tar.gz | sed 's@^//*@@' | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

This takes the list of files, delimited by newlines (`-d '\n'`) and passes them to `rm`. This will delete any fileAs usual, directories will not be removed and you will get an error message for each one.

In order to get also any directory created by the previous unpacking, you will need to use `rm -d`, which will also delete *empty* directories. The output of `tar -t` usually is ordered alphabetically, which meens that any directory will be listed before the files in them. This would mean that the directory is not yet empty when `rm` tries to delete it. To avoid this problem, we just use `sort -r` to reorder the list in reversed alphabetical order. That way any file in a directory will be deleted before `rm` attempts to remove the directory itself.

```
tar -tzf archive.tar.gz | sed 's@^//*@@' sort -r | xargs -d '\n' rm -d
```

Directories that contain files which are not in the archive (for example if the directory already existed and contained files before unpacking) will not be removed. Please do not use `rm -r` instead of `rm -d` because it may also delete files and directories that where not in the archive.

Comment: Nice approach. But I have one remark: You should be very careful if you have tar archives with absolute path names (`-P`). In that case (at least my version) `tar t ...` lists the leading `/`, but `tar c ...` extracts the files with the leading slash removed. So there's a discrepancy and you run into danger of removing something unwanted.

Comment: Thanks @mpy, you are of course correct. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I had to add -rf to my rm command, but worked great at cleaning up the mess this tarball just made.